# DataList tag only drop down in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

My input tag is placed right at the bottom of the page

Is there any way to make datalist tag to drop up automatically in Chrome? It seems to work fine in Firefox when the browser is in full screen, it will adjust and drop-up.

But in Chrome, It only drop down for some reason.

I know styling datalist tag is very limited but I hope someone can help. Thanks!